# load script from other file extension?

Tags: module, lua, require, file-extension

is it possible to load module from file with extension other than .lua?

require("grid.txt") results in:

```
module 'grid.txt' not found:
no field package.preload['grid.txt']
no file './grid/txt.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/grid/txt.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/grid/txt/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/grid/txt.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/grid/txt/init.lua'
no file './grid/txt.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/grid/txt.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
no file './grid.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/grid.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
```

I suspect that it's somehow possible to load the script into package.preaload['grid.txt'] (whatever that is) before calling require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by *load*.

If you want to execute the code in a file named `grid.txt` in the current directory, then just do `dofile"grid.txt"`. If `grid.txt` is in a different directory, give a path to it.

If you want to use the path search that `require` performs, then add a template for `.txt` in  `package.path`, with the correct path and then do `require"grid"`. Note the absence of suffix: `require` loads *modules* identified by *names*, not by *paths*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `require("grid.txt")` to work should someone try that then yes, you'll need to manually `loadfile` and run the script and put whatever it returns (or whatever require is documented to return when the module doesn't return anything) into `package.loaded["grid.txt"]`.

Alternatively, you could write your own loader just for entries like this which you set into `package.preload["grid.txt"]` which finds and loads/runs the file or, more generically, you could write yourself a loader function, insert it into `package.loaders`, and then let it do its job whenever it sees a "*.txt" module come its way.

Comment: or just do `package.path = "?.txt;"..package.path`

Comment: @hjpotter92 Assuming he wants to write `require("grid")` then yes as per lhf's comment in his answer.

Comment: package.path = "?.txt;"..package.path wins